# <Topic> Tkinter Treeview styling in the background process

Tags: tkinter, multiprocessing, garbage-collection, treeview, ttk

## [Topic] Tkinter Treeview styling in the background process

Platform specification:

- Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
- Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
- `tk.TclVersion` == `tk.TkVersion` == 8.6
- `echo 'puts [info patchlevel];exit 0' | tclsh` == 8.6.12

Hello Community,

I have created a Tk interface for a superordinate project that should function as an
independent popup like those in the `tk.filedialog` module.
Since this is to be completely deleted after the input query and this leads to

1. internal errors in Tk;
2. problems when calling the interface again

and the proposed solution of using `tk.Toplevel` did not produce the desired result,
I decided to use a wrapper that executes the interface in an independent process in
the background. The values are retrieved from the main process via a socket.

So after this issue was resolved, some other weird behavior occurred regarding the styling
of `ttk.treeview`. With more trial-and-error than I would have liked, a satisfactory
result was nevertheless achieved.

### The Issue

Although the tk objects are all created in the same process,
it seems to matter where the styling is defined.

```
<Main process>
|   <Popup process>
|   |   root = make() {
|   |       root = tk.Tk()
|   |       widget = Widget(root) {
|   |           ...
|   |           [3]
|   |       }
|   |       ...
|   |       [2]
|   |       return root
|   |   }
|   |   [1]
|   |   root.mainloop()
|
|<Popup process>.start()
```

The styling of `ttk.Treeview` is only fully applied when the styling code is
defined/executed at position `[2]` and then (before the return) `root.update_idletasks()`
is executed.

However, if the styling code is defined/executed at position `[3]` or
`root.update_idletasks()` is only executed after the return at position `[1]`,
the parameter `font=[('selected', font)]` of

```py
style = ttk.Style()

style.configure(
    "Treeview",
    weight="normal",
    size=10
)
__font = tkFont.Font()
__font.configure(underline=True, weight="bold", size=10)
style.map('Treeview', font=[('selected', __font)], background=[], foreground=[('selected', '#000000')])
```

is not applied.

*(v1)*

#### Update

Ok, the problem is probably that the object `font` only exists locally in the function context.
So if `font` is saved in an existing object, e.g. by `global font` at the beginning of the
function, the styling `font=[('selected', font)]` is also applied.

##### My guess

The problem seems to be related to the python-tk interface and the garbage collector.

So tk(-inter) uses the reference to the original object and does not create a copy or
a separate object. For some reason, this reference is not recognized by the garbage
collector and the local object is deleted after the function is finished.
Tk then handles the error internally.

*(v2)*

Asked on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77765331/topic-tkinter-treeview-styling-in-the-background-process).

The entire code can be accessed on [Github](https://github.com/srccircumflex/-Topic-Tkinter-Treeview-styling-in-the-background-process).